# Java mail API connect store in local server but not connected in development server

Tags: java, email

I am new in Java Mail API, I had tried to implement a web application using Tomcat Server which reads I reads gmail inbox and working fine. But when I upload my code to development server it throws below exception

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: http://support.google.com/mail/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 (Failure)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:660)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at sales_order.ReadInquiryViaEmail.run(ReadInquiryViaEmail.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

And my code is

```
public class ReadInquiryViaEmail implements Runnable {

    public ReadInquiryViaEmail(ServletContext context, String emailAddress,
                               String domainName, String protocol, String password) {

        this.sContext = context;
        this.domainName = domainName;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
        this.password = password;
        this.protocol = protocol;
    }

    public void run() {
        Properties imapProps;=new Properties();
        imapProps.setProperty("mail.host", domainName);
        imapProps.setProperty("mail.port", "993");
        imapProps.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", protocol);
        imapProps.setProperty("mail.imaps.starttls.enable", "true");
        imapProps.setProperty("username", emailAddress);
        imapProps.setProperty("password", password);

        int port = Integer.parseInt("993");

        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(emailAddress, password);
            }
        };

        Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(imapProps, authenticator);

        try {

            Store store = mailSession.getStore(protocol);
            store.connect(domainName, port, emailAddress, password);

            Folder folder = store.getFolder("Inbox");
            folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

            folder.getMessages();
            FlagTerm term = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
            Message[] messages = folder.search(term);
            System.out.println("messages.length > " + messages.length);
            if (messages.length > 0) {
                InternetAddress[] autoResponseEmailAddress =
                        new InternetAddress[messages.length];

                String autoResponseNames[] = new String[messages.length];
                Inquiry[] emailInquiries = new Inquiry[messages.length];
                String name = "", subject, emailAddress;

                int index = 0;
                System.out.println(" reading mails start ");
                for (int j = (messages.length - 1); j > (-1); j--, index++) {
                    messages[j].setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true);

                    Address address = messages[j].getFrom()[0];

                    autoResponseEmailAddress[j] = (InternetAddress) address;
                    autoResponseNames[j] = autoResponseEmailAddress[j].getPersonal();
                    emailAddress = autoResponseEmailAddress[j].getAddress();

                    name = autoResponseNames[j];
                    subject = messages[j].getSubject();

                    System.out.println(" name " + name);
                    System.out.println(" subject " + subject);

                }
            }
            folder.close(false);
            store.close();
            System.out.println("\n\ndone reading mails\n\n");
        } catch (javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException nspe) {
            logError(nspe);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            logError(e);
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            logError(exp);
        }
    }
}
```

Anything missing in above code ?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Google blocks authentication attempts. Try to login to Gmail account from a browser first. And make sure that you use the same account: https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Also add the following in your code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to gmail security features turned on by default.

To over come this issue do the following:

1. Sign in to your gmail account manually from web browser
2. goto https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps - select **Turn On**